# Python - returning a value that is bigger than the other?

Tags: python

```
def all_gt(nums, n):
    i = []
    for c in nums:
        if c > n:
            i += c
    return i
```

This is the code that i used and 'i' is supposed to return the value in nums larger than n.
But mine returns nothing inside the bracket. E.g.,

`all_gt([1,2,3,4], 2)  => [3,4]`

Anyone knows how to fix?
Thanks

Comment: The usual way to do this is with a list comprehension like this `i = [c for c in nums if c > n]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared `i` to be a *list*, so you need to `append` to it instead of adding.

```
def all_gt(nums, n):
    i = []
    for c in nums:
        if c > n:
            i.append(c)  ## <----- note this
    return i
```

Alternatively, you could have done this:

```
            i += [c]
```

in place of the append.

Answer (score 1):

Outdent your return statement so that it isn't executed as part of the loop.